# Isolate Maven dependencies

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to integrate Spark in a Maven project including these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I also have another dependencies using Scala 2.10

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

So I'm getting runtime exceptions because Spark cannot find Scala 2.11 functions since the project is deploying 2.10. In a standalone project with only Spark dependencies everything is working fine.

How can I isolate Spark artifacts so they can use Scala 2.11 and don't interfere with other libraries?

Comment: try use another version of scala-library instead of '2.10.4', such as '2.11.0', ... '2.12.0', or any other newer versions

Comment: I cannot use that option since it's not backwards compatible and too many changes are needed

Comment: the spark-core_2.11(version 2.1.0) depend on scala-library(version 2.11.8), it have to upgrade the version of scala-library or downgrade version of spark-core_2.11. BTW, spark-core_2.11(version 2.0.0) also using scala-library(version 2.11.8).

Comment: I know it's using Scala 2.11, what I need is to have Scala 2.10 for older dependencies and Scala 2.11 for Spark within the same project.

Comment: use [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi), or write you own classLoader to load them separately. Both are complex.

Comment: while it is considered depracated, you can use spark 2.1.0 with scala 2.10, just replace the 2_11 with 2_10 in all spark artifact ids. That said, there is a good chance 2.10 will not be supported in spark 2.2.0...

Comment: Probably you could use profiles to define different dependency versions.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible to re-factor your first app as a SpringBoot application and host as a micro-service? You can use PCF or PWS for that. With that being done your second app (which seems to be your main project) needs to consume the relevant exposed endpoints of your first app. With this approach you will be ultimately "breaking the monolith" into two loosely coupled microservices talking to each other so as to avoid the apps stepping on each other's foot which seems to be the problem now.

There are tools seem to be available to bring YARN managed Hadoop clusters, Spring framework and Scala/Spark in a single platform. You may start checking the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/springandhadoop-spark.html for the same.

I am assuming here that you are writing apps on Hadoop cluster since you are talking about a Scala project invoking / consuming spark utilities.

You can give this a shot. A little-bit refactoring in the code level is required, but the architecture of these two apps will be scalable and maintainable to avoid all and any kind of dependency issues in the future.